# How to properly hyperlink class-based views in Django documentation generator?

Tags: python, django, documentation, admin, docutils

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/#documentation-helpers) shows information on how to make link to the view, but not class-based view. When I do:

```
"""
    Redirects to :view:`accounts.ProfileDetailView`
"""
```

It shows link with url to: `/admin/doc/views/accounts.profiledetailview/`, but the actual docs  page for the class-based view is `/admin/doc/views/accounts.views.ProfileDetailView/` (i.e. with good case sensitivity and also `.views` in the middle).

I can easily add `.views` into the string, but cannot force the case sensitivity.

Am I able to fix it? How?